# Can mariaDB contain indices only with data coming from remote tables?

Tags: index, mariadb, table, remote

I'm trying to think through a setup with a central `mariaDB` instance (A) accessing data on physically remote servers (B).

All queries to the database (A) can be answered from indices only. Indices are read-only that is re-indexing is triggered from the remote-server (B) at certain intervalls (once per day).

I'm far from a specialist in database things, so when searching around and finding [mariadb CONNECT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect/) I was wondering:

**Question:**
Is it at all possible to have a `mariaDB` database (A) containing "indices only" and the underlying tables being kept on remote locations (B)? If it was, is it feasable?

Thanks for some ideas!

Comment: I have one question for you: WHY?

Comment: Hm. Data will be kept and maintained in the remote location, so I was thinking if it was possible to keep it there and still have "something" query-able like an index - says me, the "database-whitebelt"

Comment: An InnoDB table is just an index anyway, so a table + N indexes is just (N+1) indexes. Why not just use plain old replication? Think of the table as just one additional index (which it is!)

Comment: ok. I got the point in terms of feasability. Now would it be technically possible?

Answer (score 0):

No: local instance can't know when remote tables are updated.

Also, I suggest you use `SPIDER` instead of `CONNECT`.